# Postgres syntax error on a DELETE query

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I've successfully run this query as a `SELECT` using DataGrip directly against the specified table, but when I try to run it as a `DELETE`, it's resulting in a syntax error.

Code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_str.format(*connection_args))

with conn, conn.cursor() as curs:
    delete_duplicates_command = """
            DELETE FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY {pk} 
                ORDER BY _ts DESC) as row_num
            FROM {table}) as t
            WHERE t.row_num != 1;
        """.format(table=target_table, pk=primary_key)

    curs.execute(delete_duplicates_command)
```

Error:

```
Migration failed: syntax error at or near "("
    LINE 2:             DELETE FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTIT...
                                    ^
```

Both the table and primary key are valid string values. I've tried reformatting this command multiple ways ways to no avail.

FYI I'm using `psycopg2==2.6` and `Python 2.7.3`

---

Trying to rewrite the query to avoid doing a select inside the delete:

```
WITH ordered_table AS
    (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pk ORDER BY _ts DESC) as row_num
        FROM orig_table)
DELETE FROM orig_table
USING ordered_table
WHERE ordered_table.row_num > 1;
```

Which results in the follow error:
`ERROR: syntax error at or near "DELETE"`

Comment: You cannot `delete from <query>`, see [the proper syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-delete.html).

Comment: Good point klin. I've posted the updated version of the query (still not working). Any thoughts?

Comment: Postgres version? (`select version();`)

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1088